# c# USB device choose and input read to database (windows form)

Tags: c#, winforms, usb

I would like to create a program where i can read the USB devices name and if it is ready then i would like to send the input data (key hitting or something like this) to a database.

Fisrt:

I try to make an USB device reader: (OS win 7 64bit):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string deviceQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID = '{0}'", deviceID);
        using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(deviceQuery))
            if (searcher.Get().Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show(@"Device not detected");
}
private void btn_usbread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        lb_usbdevice.Text = deviceID;
}
```

But it could not find any device. I tried with

```
string deviceQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win64_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID = '{0}'", deviceID);
```

This case there is no feilure but button event is still empty :(.

Could you help me where is the problem? I would like to see all USB devices to choose one them for the next step.

Comment: Have you tried using a .net lib for accessing usb devices? Something like http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html?

Comment: Thanks Pikoh but i could not find a good one with C# examples.

Comment: The one i just linked has C# samples...

Comment: Ok than i wont use exrta but only windows basic librarys